# Probability: Solving a problem in two ways gives different answers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

Having been preparing for my upcoming exam, I have stumbled upon a seemingly simple problem:

> A smallest enclosing circle for a set of points P, |P| > 2 is
>   determined by a subset of exactly 3 points of P. What is the
>   probability of chosing exactly those points when picking 3 points at
>   random with equal probability.

My first train of thought was to see it as a modified "urn problem": For the first pick, I have all 3 points to chose from, i.e. the probability is $\frac{3}{n}$. For the second pick, you have 2 "good" points left and, i.e. probability $\frac{2}{n}$. Lastly, you are left with 1 "good" points, so $\frac{1}{n}$.  This gives me $\frac{6}{n^3}$, which does not match the solution our professor had.

The way she did it, the problem was abstracted into "chosing a subset of size 3 of n points at random with equal probability", i.e. $\frac{1}{\binom{n}{3}}$.

**My question:** Why is my first idea incorrect? I have solved a seemingly similar problem with my first train of thought:

> You have a bag full of colourful crayons, each coloured with one of n
>   colours. If you draw m crayons out of the bag uniformly at random
>   (without replacement), what is the probability of all of them being of
>   the same colour?

All I did there was multiply: $\frac{m}{n} * \frac{m-1}{n-1} * ... \frac{1}{n- (m-1)}$.

**As the problems seemed so similar, I expected that leaving the denominator constant would give the solution for the first problem...**

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Felix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first choice for the triangle you indeed have $n$ points to choose from. But then you have taken a point away, and the second choice is from $n-1$ points (you don't want to pick the same point twice).

Comment: I completely missed that, the professor at one point said that it is possible for a point to be chosen twice (as you pick points at random).

Can one generalize that multiplying the possibilities as you stated and making the binomial coefficient are equivalent?

Am I correct in the assumption that the Binomial coefficient only makes sense when you are **not** allowed to chose a point twice? I reckon, if you were to allow a point to be chosen twice, you would have to duplicate all elements, i.e. have (2n choose k) instead if (n choose k).

Comment: @iMrFelix The binomial coefficient counts choices without repetition. If repetition is allowed you need to analyse the situation as there are subtly different possibilities, depending on whether order matters and on the choice conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you pick the points does not matter. In your solution it does, so you have to divide by $6$ (the number of ways to order 3 picks). Then the solutions should agree.